# Retrieve and interpret large amounts of data from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm an Electrical Test Engineer. Programming experience with C, mostly for devices with 256B of RAM or less. And have not a lot of experience with SQL databases...

We got a database with production data, serial numbers and testing results.
At the creation of the database no tools was created to retrieve the data.
If we can't retrieve the data, the database may as well not exist.

We have the data, the database exists. I want to create tools to retrieve and interpret data. And in the future do statistical analysis on the data.

The database has over 500k unique devices. With over 10 million measurements.

My question is: what's the most sensical way to retrieve and display the data?

For instance: a program what loops trough every entry and records the data will be complicated to write and will take days to complete.

The program and query's get complicated very fast.

We have Device types, Batch numbers, Serial numbers.

```
For every DISTINCT (DeviceType)
    For Every DISTINCT (Batch number)
        COUNT DISTINCT (Serial number) where...
            NOT IN User <> 'development'...
            AND Testing result <> 'FAIL'...
            AND Date between ... and ...
```

Not to mention the measurement data, as each device may be tested multiple times. It seemed a trivial task, I'm now overwhelmed by the complexity.

I will create the code and query's myself. What I ask is help finding a strategy.

Comment: The most sensible way to retrieve and display data is to use SQL.  I'm not sure what your question really is.

Comment: Without a lot more information there isn't much we can offer here. To summarize your question. You have a database and you want to get data out of it. Since we don't know what you are trying to accomplish about all I can offer is to suggest using queries to retrieve the data.

Comment: You are both right. What I wanted to know if there was a way around nested loops and lots of query's. There does not seem to be... I'm going to try Tom's suggestion.

Comment: As you tagged your question as [tag:sql-server], and you have no experience, I would recommend you to use MS-Access. It is good starter point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself what questions you want to answer by recourse to the data. If the data is recorded in the most granular way possible, then it may be appropriate to consider common grouping or aggregation methods. These might include grouping by device, or location, or something else - each of these dimensions will have a business interpretation.

Writing down 3 top business requests should give you a starting point for constructing your extract/analysis strategy.

Next, try and draw together a data model, find out what tables exist, what references and relations they have to one another.

Together, between the questions you want to answer and the table-design, you should then be in a position to start constructing sensible general use queries.

Sometimes you may find different business questions can be answered using a common view of the data - when you're happy with an extract path, you can write this out using a common query language called [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) and - if appropriate, create a VIEW using that language. This abstracts the problem and makes it more convenient for users to actually get the answers they're looking for.

Your database will provide tools to write and run SQL statements, and you will need to refer to the documentation for your database to figure out how that happens - it's usually similar, but implementations differ across databases.